# How to get that off-kilter feeling from sungazer?

Tags: theory, jazz

Sungazers music has this beautiful off-kilter feeling to it and I hope to replicate it in my own music. How is this achieved?

examples:

(not sungazer but at 6:30)

Comment: You mention wanting to know about the notes and chords played, but what sounds off kilter to me in the first piece is the meter--the number of beats in each measure, for example.  Are you sure you want to limit the answers to just the actual notes and chords played?

Comment: thank you for the advice, I do agree that I shouldn't limit myself so I have deleted this section

Comment: Adam Neely explains much of what he and the band are doing on his channel. He has a video on "how to play with a drunk feel", various videos on microtonal approaches... so, have you watched them and tried to apply the techniques? If you did and didn't succeed, he has occasional Q&As on his channel. I'd try to get my answer straight from the horse's mouth if I were you, especially since this horse is so willing to share.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple way to do this is to utilize odd meters, such as 9/8, or 11/8. These allow you to create stumbling rhythm sections. And as a commenter stated, Adam himself has several videos detailing how to do this in much more depth.